# How can i get the uilabel text changed upon clicking a UIbuttion in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have UITableViewCell Cell Shown Below this Custom cell have two buttons for adding/subtracting the product quantity.I have set the current quantity as + button tag and able to get.but how will i set the label text 2 and so on when user click the + button.

[image: I have UITableViewCell]

> 

i don't want to change the DataSource of the table view ie by adding the incremented value in the array from where the data coming into the UITableView and then reloading the tableView.

Also upon exploring the SO i Find

```
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblCart];
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tblCart indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

to get the NSIndexPath for the cell that have the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve the required funtionality using the following

```
-(void)addQ:(UIButton*)sender

{
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblCart];
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tblCart indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
    NSInteger num=sender.tag;
    num=num+1;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    NSLog(@"hitIndex.row  is %ld",(long)hitIndex.row);
    [self alterTheQuantity:hitIndex.row  Num:num];
}
-(void)minusQ:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSInteger num=sender.tag;
    num=num-1;
    if(num <0){
        num=0;
    }
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblCart];
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tblCart indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

    [self alterTheQuantity:hitIndex.row  Num:num];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create `delegate` method on your `CustomCell.h` file

```
@class CustomCell;

@protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)plusButtonClick:(CustomCell *)cell;

@end
```

inside interface of .h file

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property id<CellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Then on Click event of your plusButton call the `delegate` from `CustonmCell.m` like

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(plusButtonClick:)]) {
        [delegate plusButtonClick:self];
    }
```

Now at your `viewController`

```
-(void)plusButtonClick:(CustomCell *)cell{
int count = [[cell.textLabel text]intValue];
count++;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
}
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your cell is custom, with its own custom Class, you should probably rather do it there, instead of in the `TableViewController` (e.g `MyCell`).
You have buttons in your class, so I presume you do have a custom class and have `-(IBAction)`s for each button? Or did you do something else? If you aren't doing this, then I recommend it. Then you could solve it with something like this (in `MyCell.m`):

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@implementation MyCell

/*...*/

-(IBAction)addQuantity{
    self.quantity++;
    [self.txtQuantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.quantity]];
    //Do something more here
}
-(IBAction)subQuantity{
    self.quantity--;
    if(self.quantity<0){self.quantity = 0;}
    [self.txtQuantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.quantity]];
    //Do something more here
}

/*...*/

@end
```

In this example, you'd have the property `@property int quantity;` declared in your `MyCell.h`-file, as well as the `IBOutlet` for the text-field named `textQuantity`. This code will only update the label's text, and the cell's own quantity-property, but not the data source. However, you should update the data-source as well (though you don't have to reload the tableView). So where I've written "//Do something more here", you should probably create a delegate-method from your custom cell to the tableView or tableViewController letting it know that the quantity-field was changed.